# Open file by name only, no extension

Tags: command-line, batch-file, cmd

How can I open any type of file in a .bat by providing only a name of the file, no extension?
I want to let windows decide the application to use.

example:

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe E:\SomeFolder\

%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe E:\SomeFolder\file1

Comment: This is unclear. Windows decides which program to use based on the extension. Additionally, an extension is part of the file name, it's also a convention. You are also asking "How can I open a file without the complete name of the file".

Comment: I need to open up excel files, and I do not know weather the file ends with .xlsx or .xls

Comment: Both extensions should launch Excel. If one or both does not, that can be fixed. Try right-clicking on one of the "broken" files in Windows Explorer, select Open With, select Excel from the list of applications, check the "always use this application" checkbox, then click OK.

Comment: Well, it might be possible to write a batch script that would pick up the first entry in the directory matching the name, but would that really solve the problem without introducing another one? What if there were both `.xls` and `.xlsx` versions? What if there was also an `.exe` with the same name? Anyway, I think the primary issue is why/how you end up in a situation where you've got only a name, without the extension. If that's because Windows Explorer doesn't display them, well, just change the corresponding setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use START command:

```
start "Any title" E:\SomeFolder\
start "Any title" E:\SomeFolder\file1
```

Taken from Start help:

```
If Command Extensions are enabled, external command invocation
through the command line or the START command changes as follows:
```

.

```
non-executable files may be invoked through their file association just
    by typing the name of the file as a command.  (e.g.  WORD.DOC would
    launch the application associated with the .DOC file extension).
    See the ASSOC and FTYPE commands for how to create these
    associations from within a command script.
```

.

```
When searching for an executable, if there is no match on any extension,
then looks to see if the name matches a directory name.  If it does, the
START command launches the Explorer on that path.  If done from the
command line, it is the equivalent to doing a CD /D to that path.
```

Note that previous description imply that the pure filename must also execute the right application, with no START command. To pick up the first file with a given name:

```
for %%f in (name.*) do set "filename=%%f" & goto continue
:continue
```

... and to execute it:

```
%filename%
```

PS - Note that you want "to let windows decide the application to use", but in your example you explicitly select `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe` as the application to use. So?